# Can somebody help me with this mathematical induction proof?

Tags: induction, recursive-algorithms

[image]

It's a recursive equation and I'm not sure how to demonstrate it through mathematical induction.

Comment: Well, given that you are handed the final form, an inductive proof should be straight forward.

Comment: @lulu thank you, I honestly have no idea how to do it

Comment: What have you tried? The way to do induction is like this: Assume for some value $n$ the claim holds, i.e. $a_{n} = 2+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}$ and use that to prove that the formula holds for $a_{n+1}$. Then if it holds for $n=1$ this implies it holds for $2$, $3$, and so on. Which part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you provisionally *assume* that the following statement is true for some $k$:

$a_k =2 + \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)} {12} $

Then  you use the recursion rule to *prove* (not assume!) that the next term follows the pattern, i.e.:

$a_{k+1} =2 + \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2(k+1)+1)} {12} $

The algebra basically amounts to showing (this has to be shown!) that:

$2 + \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)} {12} + \frac{(k+1)^2}2 = 2 + \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2(k+1)+1)} {12} $

which is elementary algebra, so you should be able to handle this yourself.

And you only need to end with the base case, which is simply establishing that $a_0$ is indeed $2$ as stated, which is basically showing that $2 + \frac{(0)(0+1)(2(0)+1)} {12} = 2$, which is trivial.

If you cannot follow why this process works this way, you really should go back to your study materials and refresh yourself on mathematical induction. It helps to think of it as dominoes: you first show that if you pick a domino anywhere in a long (infinite) line and topple it, the next one will surely fall also. That establishes that all dominoes from that point on will just keep falling. Then you show the base case - that the first domino in the chain definitely falls to start with. Now you've proven that all dominoes definitely fall. That's the best elementary metaphor for mathematical induction I can come up with. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you @Deepak !

Comment: @Natalia Most welcome. Sometimes a different way of stating it is all that's needed to give someone a sudden spark of insight. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ be defined as in the problem, and for convenience let $f(n) = 2 + n(n+1)(2n+1)/12$. You're being asked to prove, by induction, that $a_n = f(n)$ for all $n\ge0$. By the definition of induction, that means proving the following two statements:

- $a_0=f(0)$ (this should be easy); and
- for every $n\ge1$, if $a_{n-1}=f(n-1)$, then $a_n=f(n)$.

Do you have an idea how to prove those statements?

Comment: thanks @Greg Martin . No, I honestly don't know how to prove those statements. I'm completely lost on this subject :/ 

Edit: I mean, a0=f(0) I guess I can just change n to be 0 and calculate it but not sure if that's even a way to prove it?

Comment: Also, it should be for all n that are equal or greather than 1 so the first one should be a1 = f(1) according to your explanation ?